# opening src link without iframe

Tags: php, iframe

is there a method to open src link without iframe?

i have a script with this code:

```
<td><a target="_blank" style="margin-right:3px;" href="download/id/<?=$dl['id']?>"><?=$dl['title']?></a></td>
```

when a user clicks, it open the link using the following code:

```
<iframe  onLoad="calcHeight();" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" width="100%" height="2000" name="resize" id="resize"  src="<?=$download['url'] ?>"  />
```

how can i allow the link top open in a full page without iframe src when a user click on?

Comment: I'm confused. The top code will open the clicked link in a separate page if it's not interfered with in any way, so I don't understand where the `iframe` comes into it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rendering a page containing an `<iframe>` with the target site, you could simply redirect the user to the target URL:

```
<?php
header('Location: '.$download['url']); ?>
```

Note: There must be no other output sent to the browser before the `header()`

Comment: good idea,but this will open the link directly,i want to pass the url to download/id/xx not the main url 
this is the script to know what i means
http://aradown.info/free/index.php

if u click the links with iframe ,will open as download/id/xx,but with header,will directly open.........

Comment: I don't see any iframe involved, just a normal link with target=_blank. Please improve your question. Plus: You example link looks like some warez site, which could be NSFW for some people.